# Spring Cloud Config Server and applying @RefreshScope on an entire Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to refresh my properties, application-wide, on the fly, with Spring Cloud Config Server. I'm embedding my Config Server with my Spring Boot Client App and the app boots up perfectly.

When I try to update a property, for example: `spring.datasource.url` then I send a `POST` request to refresh the actuator : `http://localhost:9190/management/refresh`, I get the expected result :

```
[
   "spring.datasource.url"
]
```

I also created a controller for testing purposes :

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String message;

@RequestMapping("/message")
String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
}
```

However, when I hit this controller on : http://localhost:9290/message I'm still getting the old unrefreshed value for `${spring.datasource.url}`.

I have to explicitly add a @RefreshScope on my controller's class to get the updated value.

My question is : how can I achieve this application-wide ? or for each of these use cases ? :

- `@Value`s throughout my code,
- my `jdbcTemplate` that uses my `datasource`
- `<context:property-placeholder>` for my spring integration job
- logging with log4j

I'm using :

```
<spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
<spring-boot-version>1.5.9.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
```

Answer (score 3):

`@RefreshScope` is needed to recreate the bean which in turn gets the updated value from the Spring Environment. The other option is to use `@ConfigurationProperties` beans which automatically are re-bound on `/refresh` without using `@RefreshScope`. There is no option to make all beans `@RefreshScope` automatically.